# Как я это сделал(,) есть секрет

Tags: запятые

Эти все запятые нужны, не так ли?

> Котёнок — кот или кошка(,) определяется старым, проверенным способом.

> Как я это сделал(,) есть секрет.

> Почему он не придёт(,) остаётся загадкой.

> Когда он приехал(,) не является здесь-таки вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

(1) ***Котенок** — кот или кошка, —  определяется старым, проверенным способом.*

(2) ***Как** я это сделал, —  (у меня) есть секрет.*

(3) ***Почему** он не придет — остается загадкой.*

(4) ***Когда** он приехал — сейчас не вопрос.*

**Пояснение**

Во всех примерах **изъяснительная** часть **в препозиции,** поэтому нужен  **сильный знак**.

В предложениях (1) и (2) используется **единый знак**: тире недостаточно из-за осложненности конструкции.

Comment: Осложнëнности... чем?

Comment: В (1) тире стоит после котенка, во (2) дополнение пропущено, а без него (напрямую) стыковки нет. Сравнить: Как я это сделал — (это) секрет.

Comment: Типа, в первом с двумя выглядит как вставная конструкция? А во втором примере подходит сьучай из 2 или 3 пункта Розенталя? http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=152#pp152

Comment: Позже посмотрю...  Но я по слуху знаки ставлю, просто понимаю, что тире не походит.

Comment: Посмотрели ссылку? Подходят эти два объяснения?

Comment: Я помню, Максим.  Думаю, как ответить. Что-нибудь оригинальное надо... Удивительное такое.

Answer (score 0):

Обычное отделение придаточного от главной:

*Котёнок — кот или кошка, определяется старым, проверенным способом*;

*Почему он не придёт, остаётся загадкой*;

*Когда он приехал, не является здесь-таки вопросом*.

Пауза перед главной частью:

*Котёнок — кот или кошка — определяется старым, проверенным способом*;

*Почему он не придёт — остаётся загадкой*;

*Когда он приехал — не является здесь-таки вопросом*.

А вот в последнем связка *есть*, перед которой тире обычно не требуется, а запятая не нужна:

*Как я это сделал есть секрет*.

Пауза перед сказуемым:

*Как я это сделал — есть секрет*.